# Is the variety of keys a factor in performance?

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce

Working with **hadoop** and **map-reduce** framework, i was thinking that the **reduce tasks must be fine-grained** so that the different nodes that processes them can do it separately.

I think that the number of keys can influence in the granularity of the tasks. So, **is the number of keys or the variety of them a significant factor in efficiency?**

For example, if i had only one key or two, that would be a problem?

Comment: it always depends on what you want to do, so please add a small example to tell us what the problem that you want to solve is, what you have tried so far and what is the problem that you faced with your solution. Yes, the number of keys is important for efficiency, in general, but you cannot use the same number of keys in every application, regardless of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All the same keys should end in the same reducer, then, if you have only one key, you will really use only one reducer not matter if you have set 10 reducers. The remaining reducers won't have any output (but they will be instantiated).

This is a big issue named "skew data" and you require to redefine (and redistribute) your keys to be able to run the process in parallel.

Ideally the data should be distributed in sets with the same amount of records, this means that all reducers will have the same load of work.